# Git-bash UNIX: Switch columns/fields using cut?

Tags: text-processing, cut, columns, paste

So I have a file with 2 columns as follows:

```
  10  1
  11  2
  12  3
  13  4
  14  5
```

I would like to switch the columns using the cut command. I've used

```
paste <(cut -f2 file.dat) <(cut -f1 file.dat)
```

And it's giving me the following:

```
  10  1  10  1
  11  2  11  2
  12  3  12  3
  13  4  13  4
  14  5  14  5
```

Anyone know how I could use `cut` and `paste` to switch the columns? I thought the `cut -f1` or `cut -f2` would cut each field but apparently not? What am I doing wrong here?

UPDATE: 
So I'm using `-d` instead of `f` and it's giving me weird results and yet when I `cat` the file, the contents remain unchanged?

Comment: What is the output of simply `cut -f2 file.txt`?

Comment: @Jesse_b it's actually displaying the content of the file as is. I'm confused. My file is also one with .dat extension. But I don't think that changes anything?

Answer (score 2):

The default delimiter for `cut` is a tab character - if you want to `cut` space-separated data you will need to specify that using the `-d` argument.

Your input file appears to use *multiple* spaces which make it harder:

```
paste <(cut -d' ' -f5 file.txt) <(cut -d' ' -f3 file.txt)
1   10
2   11
3   12
4   13
5   14
```

or you could replace spaces by tabs (squeezing out repeats) - note that the fields become `-f3` and `-f2` because your file has leading whitespace:

```
paste <(tr -s ' ' '\t' < file.txt | cut -f3) <(tr -s ' ' '\t' < file.txt | cut -f2)
```

In this case, it would be simpler to use `awk` e.g.

```
awk '{print $2,$1}' file.txt
```

or

```
awk '{print $2,$1}' OFS='\t' file.txt
```

if you want tab-separated output (as you would get from `paste`) ex.

```
$ awk '{print $2,$1}' OFS='\t' file.txt
1   10
2   11
3   12
4   13
5   14
```

Comment: It was able to make it work with `awk` and `grep` as well, but I also have to do it using `cut` and `paste` and I tried the one suggested above and no luck.

Comment: @CodingNoob you may need to experiment with the field numbers - or count the spaces - if your input is not **exactly** as you posted (for example, does it **really** have leading whitespace, as above)?

Answer (score 0):

So I figured what I wanted to do with the following:

```
cut -d' ' -f1 file.txt > f1.txt
```

To cut and append the first column to a new file f1.txt

```
cut -d' ' -f4 file.txt > f2.txt
```

To cut and append the second column to a new file f2.txt

```
paste f2.txt f1.txt > file.txt
```

And finally to overwrite the original file.txt with switched columns.

Comment: Then ```paste <(cut -d' ' -f4 file.txt) <(cut -d' ' -f1 file.txt)``` should work as well. But note that this approach assumes that ***every*** line in your file will have a two-digit number in column 1 and a single-digit number in column 2.